# How to safely case on kind-constrained type variable in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

## Question

I want to case on a type variable that is restricted to finitely many possibilities due to a kind constraint. And I want to know statically that casing will always discover one of these finitely many possibilities. I can't figure out how to write this case without an unreachable catch-all.

As a concrete example, suppose I have a data kind

```
data{-kind-} Temp = Hot | Cold
```

Then my goal is write a function like `caseTemp` below that determines the `Temp` a given `Temp`-kinded type. Something like

```
data CaseTemp (t :: Temp) where
  IsHot :: CaseTemp 'Hot
  IsCold :: CaseTemp 'Cold

caseTemp :: forall (t :: Temp). CaseTemp t
caseTemp = ???
```

I'm OK with having some extra constraints on `caseTemp`, like the `Typeable t` in my failed attempt below. Or even with an entirely different approach.

## Failed Solution Attempt

Here is my best attempt, but it includes a branch that I think should be unreachable, and that would allow `caseTemp` to break silently if I added another constructor to `Temp` (tested in GHC 8.0.2):

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
module SOQuestion where

import Data.Typeable ( (:~:)(..), Typeable, eqT )

data{-kind-} Temp = Hot | Cold

data CaseTemp (t :: Temp) where
  IsHot :: CaseTemp 'Hot
  IsCold :: CaseTemp 'Cold
deriving instance Show (CaseTemp t)

caseTemp :: forall (t :: Temp). Typeable t => CaseTemp t
caseTemp =
  case eqT :: Maybe (t :~: 'Hot) of
    Just Refl -> IsHot
    Nothing -> case eqT :: Maybe (t :~: 'Cold) of
                 -- (GHC says this "pattern match is redundant" ???
                 -- Sounds like a bug!)
                 Just Refl -> IsCold
                 -- MY QUESTION: is there a way to eliminate the
                 -- unreachable branch here?
                 Nothing -> error "Unreachable!"
```

The problem with this attempt is that GHC believes the `Nothing -> error "Unreachable!"` branch is reachable.

## Updates

User @Alec mentions that `Any :: Temp` is a fundamental reason that it's impossible to do what I want, since e.g.

```
import GHC.Prim ( Any )
[...]
badCase :: CaseTemp Any
badCase = undefined :: CaseTemp Any
```

is accepted by GHC. However, `Any` is not `Typeable`, so it's not clear to me that putting constraints on `caseTemp` couldn't work around this.

Comment: This is because of things like `Any :: Temp`.

Comment: @Alec, thanks, I didn't know about `Any`. I updated the question with an example of what I think you're getting at.

Comment: Your comment about constraints is spot on. I encourage you to check out `singletons`. It also uses constraints to sidestep this sort of problem. Also, that is exactly the answer you were given below. :)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a direct way, because when `eqT` returns `Nothing` it doesn't come with a disequality proof.

How about using a type class?

```
class IsTemp (b :: Temp) where
  caseTemp :: CaseTemp b
```

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear that I don't care how the solution is implemented. My code was just an example of what didn't work; using `eqT` is not required. So, you are suggesting I put a `IsTemp t` constraint on all `t :: Temp` that I want to case on? That might be workable ...

Comment: Indeed, type classes are the standard way of making values depend on types.